# Embedded Groovy - loading scripts from main script

Tags: scripting, groovy, import, embedding

I'm trying to embed groovy into my application and have a problem with imports.

I wish to split scripts into several files and/or modules. Lets say I want to have some `Utilities.groovy` with `Utilities` class filled with static functions. Now I create a primary script file `main.groovy` that looks like this:

```
import static Utilities.*
Utilities.someMethod()
```

Then I try to run it with:

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(initGroovyBinding());
shell.run("F:\\ull\path\\to\\main.groovy", new String[0]);
```

And I get an error: `unable to resolve class Utilities`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `Utilities.groovy` located?

Comment: @tim_yates Near the main.groovy file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem. GroovyShell does not handle file imports in any way. However, GroovyScriptEngine does.

GroovyScriptEngine does everything GroovyShell can do plus it handles all the class dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the package. Based on your example you are trying to import Utilities from the default package.

Comment: Utilities is in same directory as main.groovy. Both files use default package.